# CSS Background Image linked right; doesnt show in Browser

Tags: html, css, image, background

I want to place an image above my nav bar and then a background image behind the nav bar as well.

My current html for the image above nav bar:

```
<div class="viewport-1"></div>
```

My current CSS for the image above nav bar:

```
.viewport-1
{
background-size: cover;
background-image: url('saultitle.png');
height: 100vh;
}
```

The image is linked in the CSS sheet as it show whenever I hover over the link in Brackets and there is a gap in the webpage where the image should be - however it does not show.

As for the nav bar image there is no gap as it is a background image but it is also linked in the CSS sheet.

Nav bar HTML

```
<div id="nav">

<table class="nav">

<tr>

<td><a href="#getting-his-start">Getting his Start</a></td>
<td><a href="#cinematic-revolution">Cinematic Revolution</a></td>
<td><a href="#experimental-phase">The Experimental Phase</a></td>
<td><a href="#logos-made-to-last">Logos Made to Last</a></td>
<td><a href="#the-nect-big-thing">The Next Big Thing</a></td>
<td><a href="#his-influence-today">His Influence Today</a></td>

</tr>

</table>
            </div>
```

Nav bar CSS

```
.nav { 
background-image: url('goldenarm.png');
width:100%;
padding:1em 0;
```

Any advice as to why they don't show?

Comment: you're missing the first bracket in your css for the viewport-1. Either this is a typo in the question or the solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi, that's just a typo - There is a bracket there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
#nav {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.viewport-1 {
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url('saultitle.png');
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/nnwn7jbg/1](https://jsfiddle.net/nnwn7jbg/1/)

```
#nav:hover .viewport-1 {transform: translate(00%,-100%);;}
```